# How to fix blank (or none) browser for MSGraph authentication screen on Android 9

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, chromium

In an android app I am using the MS-Graph API to connect to OneDrive. Up to now without problems. However, after upgrading the app to Android 9 (API 28) and running it on a new Lenovo Tab 10 also running Android 9, I get a blank log-in screen when trying to authenticate. I see the system back button - which works - but that just cancels the log-in. I can use the Chrome app on that device without problems. Below is the section of the Android Studio console output from the point that login() is called. This line may be relevant:

```
E/cr_ChildProcessConn: Failed to establish the service connection.
```

Yes, I have included the legacy apache http components. On a different device running Android 9 (Huawei) it works without errors.
Any resolution for this?

```
D/MSAAuthAndroidAdapter[login] - 166: Login started
I/LiveAuthClient: No refresh token available, sorry!
    All tokens expired, you need to call login() to initiate interactive logon
D/MSAAuthAndroidAdapter$2[onAuthComplete] - 183: LiveStatus: NOT_CONNECTED, LiveConnectSession good?: true, UserState null
D/MSAAuthAndroidAdapter$2[onAuthComplete] - 189: Received invalid login failure from silent authentication, ignoring.
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 76.0.3809.132 (code 380913237)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 14 ms (timestamps 8937-8951)
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(51)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "76.0.3809.132", actual native library version number "76.0.3809.132"
W/cr_ChildProcLH: Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, sandboxed = true
W/Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
E/cr_ChildProcessConn: Failed to establish the service connection.
I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
W/Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/ Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
W/Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
E/cr_ChildProcessConn: Failed to establish the service connection.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=925ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=32568737431608, Vsync=32569504098244, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=32569520764762, AnimationStart=32569521012054, PerformTraversalsStart=32569526247991, DrawStart=32569658014606, SyncQueued=32569659517887, SyncStart=32569659604189, IssueDrawCommandsStart=32569659747158, SwapBuffers=32569661297835, FrameCompleted=32569662622054, DequeueBufferDuration=163000, QueueBufferDuration=273000, 
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 4 for video/hevc
W/Utils: could not parse long range '146-132'
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
```